# How to improve very inefficient numpy code for calculating correlation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I wrote the following function to calculate a row by row correlation of a matrix with respect to a selected row (specified by the `index` parameter):

```
# returns a 1D array of correlation coefficients whose length matches
# the row count of the given np_arr_2d
def ma_correlate_vs_index(np_arr_2d, index):
    def corr_upper(x, y):
        # just take the upper right corner of the correlation matrix
        return numpy.ma.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]

    return numpy.ma.apply_along_axis(corr_upper, 1, np_arr_2d, np_arr_2d[index, :])
```

The problem is that the code is very, very slow and I'm not sure how to improve the performance. I believe that the use of `apply_along_axis` as well as the fact that `corrcoef` is creating a 2D array are both contributing to the poor performance. Is there any more direct way to calculate that may give better performance?

In case it matters I'm using the `ma` version of the functions to mask out some `nan` values that are found in the data. Also, the shape of `np_arr_2d` for my data is `(623065, 72)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right that there is a lot of overhead in `corrcoef`. Essentially you just want the dot product of each row with the index row, normalized to a maximum of 1.0.

Something like this will work and will be much faster:

```
# Demean
demeaned = np_arr_2d - np_arr_2d.mean(axis=1)[:, None]

# Dot product of each row with index
res = np.ma.dot(demeaned, demeaned[index])

# Norm of each row
row_norms = np.ma.sqrt((demeaned ** 2).sum(axis=1))

# Normalize
res = res / row_norms / row_norms[index]
```

This runs much more quickly than your original code. I've used the masked array methods and so I think this will work with your data containing NaN.

There may be a tiny difference in the norms, controlled by `ddof` in `corrcoef`, in which case you can calculate the row_norms using `np.ma.std` and specify the `ddof` you want.